# Does order of compared literals matter if both are evaluated?

Tags: java, if-statement, comparison

I have a rather stupid question. The point is, I often see an `if` statement looking like this:

```
private int smth;
// ...
if (3 == smth)
    // ...
```

The order feels odd for me. I even think it decreases readability of the code.

Is there any profit from putting literals that are compared to each other with binary operator in certain order within an `if` statement?

Comment: It's a habit inherited from old C and C++ compilers, which didn't warn about the most likely unintended assignment in `if (smth = 3)`. In Java, it's a completely useless thing to do.

Comment: @molbdnilo, unless you are comparing boolean values

Comment: [Yoda Conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions)

Comment: @AlexR That's a thing that's completely useless in any language.

Comment: @Trengot, thanks for the link, the only advantage I see it that it helps avoid compiler-time errors caused by typos, when one types `=` instead of `==`.

Comment: In most cases, but not always. Suppose you have boolean parameter and you have to compare with local variable into the method. You can mark parameter as `final` (BTW very good practice anyway) and *always* use it at the left size of comparison expression. This prevents you from using `=` instead of `==`.

Comment: @ RishatMuhametshin, See @Kayaman's answer regaring comparing objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any profit from putting literals that are compared to each other with binary operator in certain order within an if statement?

Not in Java, unless you do it with booleans:

```
if (false == flag)
```

In that **one case**, it helps you avoid this typo:

```
if (flag = false)
```

...which the compiler won't protect you from (that will assign `false` to `flag` and will never evaluate true).

In all other cases (anything that isn't a `boolean`), the Java compiler won't let you make that mistake. And of course, when testing booleans, it's almost always best to simply test the boolean:

```
if (!flag)
```

or

```
if (flag)
```

depending on which value you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

No, the only case where there's difference is with comparing objects using `equals`.

`if(obj != null && obj.equals("foobar"))`
vs.
`if("foobar".equals(obj))`

By using the inverted way you can avoid a null check. Since `1.7` you could just use `Objects.equals(obj, "foobar");` instead.